# I'm getting error: Missing ; before *, but I'm not missing it

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have commented everything out and the code now looks like this.

```
//AOBSClass.h

#ifndef __AOBSCLASSHDR__
#define __AOBSCLASSHDR__

#include "IDriver.h"
#include "ActuationClass.h"

namespace AOBS
{
    class AOBSClass
    {
    public:
        AOBSClass(IDriver *driver);
        ~AOBSClass();

        IDriver *drivers;

        ActuationClass act;     

    private:

    };
}

#endif



// ActuationClass.h

#ifndef __ACTUATIONCLASSHDR__
#define __ACTUATIONCLASSHDR__

#include "AOBSClass.h"

namespace AOBS
{
    class ActuationClass
    {
    public:

        ActuationClass();
        ~ActuationClass();

        AOBSClass *aobs; // This line here

    private:

    };
}
#endif
```

I keep getting the errors below on the line shown above. I have no idea what could be causing it.

```
error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
```

I'm using Visual Studio Express 2013.

Comment: Identifiers starting with `__` are reserved for use by the implementation.

Comment: Circular includes mean you haven't properly separated your logic into two classes.  You should not need to do this.

Comment: @stark: It could mean that; or it could just mean that you're including an unneeded header, as is the case here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a circular dependency. `ActuationClass.h` includes `AOBClass.h` and vice versa.

To resolve this, remove the `#include "AOBClass.h"` in `ActuationClass.h` and just forward declare the `AOBSClass`.

```
namespace AOBS
{
    class AOBSClass;      // Forward declare
    class ActuationClass
    {
    public:

        ActuationClass();
        ~ActuationClass();

        AOBSClass *aobs;

    private:

    };
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The two files include each other! Just put

```
class AOBSClass;
```

in the beginning of ActuationClass.h.

Comment: And remove `#include "AOBSClass.h"`

Answer (score 3):

You have circular includes.  Both header files include each other.  Generally, includes should go one way, like a tree structure.

A includes B includes C, etc

Also, as noted by others: a forward declaration can help with this sort of thing